# Multiple threads writing on same file

Tags: c, multithreading

I would like to know if we can use multiple threads to write binary data on the same file.

```
FILE *fd = openfile("test");
int SIZE = 1000000000;
int * table = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
// .. filling the table
fwrite(table, sizeof(*table), SIZE, fd);
```

so I wonder if i can use threads,and each thread calls fssek to seek to a different location to write in the same file.

Any idea ?

Comment: Read the documentation of `fwrite()` to learn if it's thread-safe. If not, you will need to implement your own mutex to protect it.

Comment: `int * table = sizeof(sizeof(int) * SIZE);` there seems to be missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

fwrite should be thread safe, but you'll need a mutex anyway, because you need the seek and the write to be atomic.  Depending on your platform, you might have a write function that takes an offset, or you might be able to open the file in each thread.  A better option if you have everything in memory anyway as your code suggests, would just be for each thread to fill into a single large array and then write that out when everything is done.

Comment: actualy I already have a big large array (table), but I would like to use thread to write "int * table" into my file at the same time

Comment: Is that because you expect it to be faster?  I think that's unlikely, because the write operations must serialize at some stage.  In fact the extra seeking will probably slow this down significantly.

Answer (score 1):

While `fread()` and `fwrite()` are thread safe, the stream buffer represented by the `FILE*` is not.  So you can have multiple threads accessing the same file, but not via the same `FILE*` - each thread must have its own, and the file to which they refer must be shareable - which is OS dependent.

An alternative and possibly simpler approach is to use a [memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), so that each thread treats the file as shared memory, and you let the OS deal with the file I/O.  This has a significant advantage over normal file I/O as it is truly random access, so you don't need to worry about `fseek()` and sequential read/writes etc.

Comment: Are you saying that accessing `fprintf()` and `fwrite()` using a global file pointer in multiple threads isn't safe?

Comment: @JohnStrood ;  I did not say exactly that, but yes the answer applies of any function using a `FILE*` because `FILE` is not an atomic object. Moreover the question requires independent `fseek()` operations and since the current file position is retained in the `FILE` object, in this particular case it is unworkable without wrapping the entire seek/write sequence in a mutex for both threads to ensure serialisation of operations.

Comment: Although this may well have been true of some C99 implementations, C2011 specifies "All functions that read, write, position, or query the position of a stream lock the stream before accessing it. They release the lock associated with the stream when the access is complete" ([C2011 7.21.2/8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p8)).  Note well that this refers to locking *the stream*, not the underlying file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : It is not clear to me what part of the answer or the subsequent comments you are referring to.  It was a long time ago - I am not sure I am going to change it now, but a clarification of your comment would be useful perhaps - i.e. exactly _what_ may have been true of C99?

Comment: @Clifford, I observe first that my attention was directed here by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48350184/2402272), so perhaps that will help with the context.  But I am referring to substantially your whole first paragraph.  Although the standard does not explicitly say `FILE` objects are sharable, there is no workable interpretation of its provisions concerning streams and stream locking that does not lead to that result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : Sharing a single  `FILE` object across two threads is entirely possible if access to it is locked, but not very useful if the threads need to be reading/writing/seeking independently - you would have to lock across the seek and the read/write and seek before _every_ read/write.   I make no apologies however for not relying on the availability of a C2011 compliant library; that is not a given in my work; especially at the time this question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

fseek and fwrite are thread-safe so you can use them without additional synchronization.

Comment: but calling fseek and then calling fwrite requires synchronization

Comment: @WilliamPursell It depends on the implementation. If each thread has its own file descriptor, it is safe to call them one after another without synchronization.

Comment: an example of implementation ?

Comment: @zeomega Do you mean an implementation that works fine without additional synchronization? You can just open the same file in all threads by calling `fopen` in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let each thread open the file, and make sure they write to different positions, finally let each thread close the file and your done.

**Update:**

This works on IX'ish systems, at least.

Comment: do you have a small example please ?