# Most efficient way for multiple threads to write to a single file in C

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management

Before I proceed with my question I first have referred to the answer on [Multiple threads writing on same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565498/multiple-threads-writing-on-same-file) which designates making threads write to a memory mapped file and let the OS handle disk IO. My question is I have a program where each thread is dealing with around 1GB worth of data in each file and they all need to write the data according to their timestamp to a single file, with the following output in chronlogical order. The underlying assumption is that the input file to each thread is already in chronological order. My first approach was to use fwrite to write the data however this introduces a performance penalty and each thread writing must wait till it sees the corresponding size change in the output file before releasing the lock(basically fwrite takes time which is obvious). Now if I substitute my writing via fwrite to a memory mapped file two questions arise in my mind: 1) Is it viable to memory map 4G into a file , I have RAM of around 16G. 2) Will the performance change drastically in comparison to fwrite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to write to the same file from multiple Threads.

Use the multiple Threads to sort the entries from each file into a data structure in memory (modern computers should have the 4-8GB of memory needed to do this) and then use a single thread to write to the file. You may be able to achieve performance gains if you use a mutex lock around a Queue (or similar data structure) and have a "writer" Thread which pops items off the queue to be written to the file, and several "reader" Threads which each (atomically) push items to the queue.