# Do I need a mutex to protect a int value which could be get/set via sysfs?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, locking, driver

Multiple user space processes could access this value at the same time so I guess we should use some locks or memory barrier things for safe but I could find quite a lot code in linux driver who doesn't, or just protect the write case.
Do we really need a mutex for both read case and write case?

Comment: Are you using shm ? (Shared Memory Segment)

Comment: Not really. My case is, for example, I have a rw register "REG", and in driver I cached it's value with "int reg", then I create a sysfs file, let's say, "/sys/.../reg". When user echo an int value to "/sys/.../reg", this value will be written to REG, and cached to "int reg"; When user cat "/sys/.../reg", driver will just give "int reg" to user. My question is, do I need add a mutex to protect "int reg" for both echo and cat case?

Comment: If you are writing in files with multiple process / threads, maybe this post could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565498/multiple-threads-writing-on-same-file

Comment: Does it really make sense to talk about the fread/fwrite here? What if people use read/write system call directly? Also, I think there is some different between regular file system and sysfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the CPU and the system that the code is executed. Actually you can do this without synchronization techniques if the operation is **atomic**. As long as you're not sure about this it's better to use a synchronization object. For int/dword values most of the time people do this without sych object.

Read this article
http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/

and also a same issue [Are C++ Reads and Writes of an int Atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and you links:-)